# not receiving jwt after logging in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I've been trying to work on a movie app using the MERN stack. After having a few issues regarding the backend of one the features, I went back through my code and realised it doesnt seem that the jwt is being recieved after login. I have no issues with the signup and login other that it seemingly not obtaining the jwt

Heres the authJwt file

```
    const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
    const config = require("../config/auth.config.js");
    const db = require("../models");
    const User = db.user;
    const Role = db.role;
    
    verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
      let token = req.headers["x-access-token"];
    
      if (!token) {
        return res.status(403).send({ message: "No token provided!" });
      }
    
      jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(401).send({ message: "Unauthorized!" });
        }
        req.userId = decoded.id;
        next();
      });
    };
    
    isAdmin = (req, res, next) => {
      User.findById(req.userId).exec((err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send({ message: err });
          return;
        }
    
        Role.find(
          {
            _id: { $in: user.roles }
          },
          (err, roles) => {
            if (err) {
              res.status(500).send({ message: err });
              return;
            }
    
            for (let i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
              if (roles[i].name === "admin") {
                next();
                return;
              }
            }
    
            res.status(403).send({ message: "Require Admin Role!" });
            return;
          }
        );
      });
    };
    
    isModerator = (req, res, next) => {
      User.findById(req.userId).exec((err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send({ message: err });
          return;
        }
    
        Role.find(
          {
            _id: { $in: user.roles }
          },
          (err, roles) => {
            if (err) {
              res.status(500).send({ message: err });
              return;
            }
    
            for (let i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
              if (roles[i].name === "moderator") {
                next();
                return;
              }
            }
    
            res.status(403).send({ message: "Require Moderator Role!" });
            return;
          }
        );
      });
    };
    
    const authJwt = {
      verifyToken,
      isAdmin,
      isModerator
    };
  module.exports = authJwt;
```

Heres the user routes file. When I go to http://localhost:8081//api/test/user after logging in, it displays the message "No token provided!"

```
const { authJwt } = require("../middlewares");
const controller = require("../controllers/user.controller");

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    next();
  });

  app.get("/api/test/all", controller.allAccess);

  app.get("/api/test/user", [authJwt.verifyToken], controller.userBoard);

  app.get(
    "/api/test/mod",
    [authJwt.verifyToken, authJwt.isModerator],
    controller.moderatorBoard
  );

  app.get(
    "/api/test/admin",
    [authJwt.verifyToken, authJwt.isAdmin],
    controller.adminBoard
  );
};
```

Here's my server.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const dbConfig = require("./app/config/db.config");

const app = express();

var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:8081"
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(express.json());

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const db = require("./app/models");
const Role = db.role;

db.mongoose
  .connect(`mongodb+srv://tami00:MEUxClWqUNbLz359@cluster0.gmvao.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority`, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully connect to MongoDB.");
    initial();
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error("Connection error", err);
    process.exit();
  });

// simple route
app.use('/api/favourite', require('./app/routes/favourite.routes'));
// routes
// require(".app/routes/favourite.routes")(app);
require("./app/routes/auth.routes")(app);
require("./app/routes/user.routes")(app);

// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});

function initial() {
  Role.estimatedDocumentCount((err, count) => {
    if (!err && count === 0) {
      new Role({
        name: "user"
      }).save(err => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("error", err);
        }

        console.log("added 'user' to roles collection");
      });

      new Role({
        name: "creator"
      }).save(err => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("error", err);
        }

        console.log("added 'creator' to roles collection");
      });

      new Role({
        name: "watcher"
      }).save(err => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("error", err);
        }

        console.log("added 'watcher' to roles collection");
      });
    }
  });
}
```

**FRONTEND**
AuthService

```
import axios from "axios";

const API_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/auth/";

class AuthService {
  login(username, password) {
    return axios
      .post(API_URL + "signin", {
        username,
        password
      })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.data.accessToken) {
          localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
        }

        return response.data;
      });
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem("user");
  }

  register(username, email, password) {
    return axios.post(API_URL + "signup", {
      username,
      email,
      password
    });
  }

  getCurrentUser() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));;
  }
}

export default new AuthService();
```

Auth Header

```
export default function authHeader() {
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

  if (user && user.accessToken) {
    // return { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + user.accessToken }; // for Spring Boot back-end
    return { 'x-access-token': user.accessToken };       // for Node.js Express back-end
  } else {
    return {};
  }
}
```

Login Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Form from "react-validation/build/form";
import Input from "react-validation/build/input";
import CheckButton from "react-validation/build/button";

import AuthService from "../services/auth.service";

const required = value => {
  if (!value) {
    return (
      <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        This field is required!
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
    this.onChangeUsername = this.onChangeUsername.bind(this);
    this.onChangePassword = this.onChangePassword.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: "",
      loading: false,
      message: ""
    };
  }

  onChangeUsername(e) {
    this.setState({
      username: e.target.value
    });
  }

  onChangePassword(e) {
    this.setState({
      password: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleLogin(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      message: "",
      loading: true
    });

    this.form.validateAll();

    if (this.checkBtn.context._errors.length === 0) {
      AuthService.login(this.state.username, this.state.password).then(
        () => {
          this.props.history.push("/profile");
          window.location.reload();
        },
        error => {
          const resMessage =
            (error.response &&
              error.response.data &&
              error.response.data.message) ||
            error.message ||
            error.toString();

          this.setState({
            loading: false,
            message: resMessage
          });
        }
      );
    } else {
      this.setState({
        loading: false
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-md-12">
        <div className="card card-container">
          <img
            src="//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png"
            alt="profile-img"
            className="profile-img-card"
          />

          <Form
            onSubmit={this.handleLogin}
            ref={c => {
              this.form = c;
            }}
          >
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
              <Input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name="username"
                value={this.state.username}
                onChange={this.onChangeUsername}
                validations={[required]}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
              <Input
                type="password"
                className="form-control"
                name="password"
                value={this.state.password}
                onChange={this.onChangePassword}
                validations={[required]}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <button
                className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                disabled={this.state.loading}
              >
                {this.state.loading && (
                  <span className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"></span>
                )}
                <span>Login</span>
              </button>
            </div>

            {this.state.message && (
              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                  {this.state.message}
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
            <CheckButton
              style={{ display: "none" }}
              ref={c => {
                this.checkBtn = c;
              }}
            />
          </Form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: const { authJwt } = require("../middlewares"); should be const authJwt = require("../middlewares"); // notice I have removed the curly braces

Comment: Try putting a console.log on req.headers["x-access-token"]; and req.headers

Comment: @adhinarayan I tried that and got an error in my server file saying Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object

Comment: @adhinarayan I've edited it to alos include my server file

Comment: @adhinarayan it prints out "undefined" and
[Function: header]

Comment: So I believe you are not setting the headers in the frontend i.e react. If you are using axios.. I believe you need to send the token in x-access-token header.. you can check the axios docs

Comment: Hi, were you able to fix this problem?